# Why this Java code prints null for an existing key value?

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception

This program return null for existing key-value.

Code:

```
File file = new File("document.xml");
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller=context.createUnmarshaller();
Document document=(Document)unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

Map<String, String> map=document.getValues();
System.out.println("Values="+map);
System.out.println(map.get("100300IDG"));
```

Output:-

```
  Values={240400MAHAR=100010101, 100300IDG=44444444, 200200MDM=11221321, 341095TRAVERS=7070070, 340203BRUCKNER=545454, 490423SALEM=64845674, 100490MSC=2222222, 240371PRODUCTION=7777777, 250341FASTENAL=121212}

  null
```

Code for document class.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Document {
private Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();


//Getter and setter for values


}
```

Document file that contain values and these values are populated into document object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<document>
<values>
<entry>
    <key>240400MAHAR</key>
    <value>100010101</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>100300IDG</key>
    <value>44444444</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>200200MDM</key>
    <value>11221321</value>
</entry>
</values>
</document>
```

Comment: And are you sure the strings are *actually* identical?

Comment: Please post how you populate the map that gets returned by `getValues()`.

Comment: What type is the Map instance?

Comment: @nikpon it is HashMap.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis map is populated by Jabx xml parser

Comment: @imssbora Don't tell us. Show us.

Comment: Can you also provide sample XML?

Comment: The XML is invalid for the `Document` class you posted. If we wrap it with `<document>` tags, it runs fine and doesn't exhibit the behavior you are talking about. Are you sure this is what you have?

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is that the Key objects used in the `Map` returned by `document.getValues()` print `String` values like `100300IDG`  but aren't actually `String` instances. Therefore `map.get("100300IDG")` is comparing a `String` object with a non-String object (or vice-versa) and returning `null` because none could be found.

This all depends on how `document.getValues()` is implemented. Take for example

```
private static Map<String, String> getValues() {
    Map map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(new MyClass("100300IDG"), "44444444");
    return map;
} 
...
// with  
public class MyClass {
    private String string;

    public MyClass(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }
}
```

It would print

```
{100300IDG=44444444}
```

But wouldn't actually contain an entry with key `"100300IDG"`.

Make sure your key types match. The compiler can't do much here.

---

Or maybe another thread removes the entry between printing and getting it.

Comment: @DavidWallace It uses [unchecked conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9) (you will get warnings), but unchecked conversion doesn't do anything to the object, only the reference.

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  I realised that a bit too late.  I actually deleted my comment before I saw your reply.  Good answer +1.